# XSL transformation attributes to elements

Tags: xslt

I would like to convert  xml attributes of input xml to elements of output xml.
Example

```
<Price price1="2" price2="3" total="5" other="x" tax="2"/> to

 <Price>
   <price1>2</price1>
   <price2>3</price2>
   <total>5</total>
   <other>x</other>
   <tax>2</tax>
 </Price>
```

I tried like

```
   <xsl:element name="Price">
   <xsl:for-each select="*:Price/@*">
   <xsl:element name="*>
  <xsl:value-of select="@*"/>
  </xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:element></xsl:element>
```

Not able to get the required output.Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
<xsl:template match="Price">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="@*">
            <xsl:element name="{name()}">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```